# Microsoft SQL Server PIVOT/UNPIVOT questions

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have the below snippets:

```
CREATE TABLE [SINGLE_COL]
(
    [COL1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [COL2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [COL3] [varchar](50) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO [SINGLE_COL]
VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C')
GO
INSERT INTO [SINGLE_COL]
VALUES ('D', 'E', 'F')
GO

select * from [SINGLE_COL]
```

It returns like this:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
A    B    C
D    E    F
```

I want to turn all the rows into a single column like below:

```
COL
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Here is what I do in oracle:

```
SELECT col FROM SINGLE_COL
UNPIVOT (col FOR col1 IN (col1, col2, col3));
```

It's very simple and easy to do in Oracle but not in MS SQL Server!

I believe that I have to use a function UNPIVOT but how??

Thank you!

Comment: In case it helps someone, can you [edit] in the query you'd use in Oracle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
select Cols from [SINGLE_COL]
unpivot
(
  Cols
  for col in (Col1, Col2, Col3)
) u;
```

Comment: Nope, your query only returns COL1, COL2, COL3, COL1, COL2, COL3. Did you really run your query? Thx.

Comment: @rtn60350 I edited it, You can check it again

Comment: yep, it works now. Thank you.